# A child browser window closing itself apparently breaks Watir-webdriver's link to the parent window?

Tags: ruby, webdriver, watir-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

In Chrome, using watir-webdriver, I click a button that opens a child browser window.

I do:

```
@browser.window(title: 'Child').use
```

I successfully interact with various items in that child window.

Very shortly, there is an action done in this window that the site considers was the "point" of opening the window in the first place. e.g.,

```
@browser.button(title: 'Button').click
```

When this action is performed, the child window closes itself.

When I tell watir-webdriver to go back to using the parent window, however, I get an error:

```
@browser.window(title: 'Parent').use # => results in
# Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchWindowError: emptyScript execution failed; 
# The window could not be found
```

The reason I believe this is a Selenium/Watir-webdriver bug is because the following code works:

```
@browser.window(title: 'Child').use
# ... Now I do various things in the child window that do NOT
# ... cause it to close itself. They all work as expected.
# ...
puts @browser.window(title: 'Parent').present? #=>true
@browser.window(title: 'Child').close
puts @browser.window(title: 'Parent').present? #=>true
@browser.window(title: 'Parent').use # => No error thrown
```

The only difference is the action that causes the child window to close itself.

I notice that the watirspec code does not have a test case for a self-closing window, so perhaps this is an overlooked aspect of the windows code in watir-webdriver.

Okay, so here is the code that *you* can run, to see this problem yourself:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
@b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
@b.goto 'ckeditor.com/demo#full'
@b.div(id: 'cke_editor1').link(title: 'Link').click
@b.link(title: 'Browse Server').wait_until_present
@b.link(title: 'Browse Server').click
@b.window(title: 'CKFinder').use { 
  @b.frame(title: 'CKFinder').link(id: 'r0').right_click
  @b.frame(title: 'CKFinder').frame(id: 'cke_22_frame').wait_until_present 
  @b.frame(title: 'CKFinder').frame(id: 'cke_22_frame').link(id: 'cke_200').click
}
```

That will result in this error:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchWindowError: emptyScript execution failed;
The window could not be found
```

Don't say I never did nuthin' for ya! :-)

Now, before you go asking "Why are you testing a 3rd Party editing tool, you crazy guy?" I will answer that for you: I'm not.

What I'm testing is that the source code that gets generated by the CKEditor tool gets properly updated in a particular situation (which goes far beyond the scope of this question here). To set that up requires that I first know what that source code *is* so that, later, I can verify it gets properly updated by a different process. And to do that, I must first properly set it up, using the CKEditor's link tool. Capiche?

Comment: are you using `selenium` or `watir` webdriver?

Comment: Watir-webdriver - like it says in my first sentence. :-)

Comment: I looked at watirspec and abe is right in this regard.  we have a test there to see that we can see the child window, but that is it.  We do not for example have a test for the example code show in the rdoc for use..

Comment: Will the same problem happen if you pass the popup actions to `use` as a block?

Comment: Actually, no. When I pass the actions to .use, *nothing* happens in the pop-up window. It's quite annoying.

Comment: @JustinKo, I have a better answer for you, now. I tweaked my syntax inside the .use block to make sure things would work.

Here's what returns when I do a command that does *not* close the child window:
    `=> #<Watir::Window:0x7924173ec77a9a2 located=true>`

(i.e., everything is lovely)

...And here's what returns when the .use block clicks the link that causes the window to close itself:

    `Timeout::Error: Timeout::Error
 from /Users/abrahamheward/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:146:in \`rescue in rbuf_fill'`

(i.e., everything is sucky)

Comment: How is the popup getting closed by the button? I tried a popup window that had a close link with `href="javascript:window.close();"` and was able to successfully return to working with the parent window.

Comment: It's a little obscure.  Here's the HTML for the link that closes the window: `<a href="#" onclick="LinkItem('https://dev-1.cle.rsmart.com/direct/assignment/03d3cdc9-704d-41e6-847f-c84a97db60a7', true);return false;">Link Text Goes Here</a>` ... My workaround for this problem right now is going to be to just grab that HTML and parse out the "LinkItem" with some regexp, then close the window with the Watir .close method.

Comment: Abe can you edit the orignal question to perhaps show the code you used for the block method, and the resulting error?  it's easier if we have it up there, nicely formatted, than having to dig through comments

Comment: I'm not entirely sure the additional code will be illuminating, but I'll put it up first thing tomorrow when I'm back at my desk.

Comment: Okay. Demo code that duplicates the problem has now been added, @ChuckvanderLinden

Comment: Thanks, providing something reproducable will help I'm sure one way or the other.

Comment: Note that an issue has been created for watir-webdriver - https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/issues/196

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get back to the first window opened you can use

```
@browser.windows[0]
```

You may also be able to do something like this (not tested)

```
@browser.windows.each do |window|
  if window.title.include?(target_string)
    window.use
  end
end
```

Comment: That would be great if the error didn't occur prior to this line of code being run (which is what will happen, unfortunately).